# infinite scroll with group marker (jquery/jquery mobile)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-waypoints, jquery-mobile-listview

I've seen in different apps an implementation of infinite scrolling with a marker. I think the  apps have been written in objective-c but I'm wondering if there's a jquery equivalent (or a js library).

What I'm looking for is an infinite scroll with a group marker for some data. For example, showing all the events for a day. The group marker shows "today" and a list of events for the day. After scrolling, "Tomorrow"'s marker is shown and replaces "Today"'s and so on.

Example of an app doing just this here  [image]

Is there a jquery library doing that ? I couldn't find the correct terminology for the marker (today, tomorrow) so that's maybe why I couldn't find a discussion on stackoverflow. Is group marker a good way of describing it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly it can be done. I don't know if this is exactly 100% similar but it is close.

jQuery Mobile has something called listview dividers and they can be implemented dynamically.

Let's say you have dynamically puled data from a server and listview has been populated but not refreshed. Your listview content would look like this:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="MessagesList" data-autodividers="true">
    <li date="2013-03-03"><a href="#">Event 1</a></li>
    <li date="2013-03-02"><a href="#">Event 2</a></li>
    <li date="2013-03-01"><a href="#">Event 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now, before you refresh and enhance listview markup you will initialize generation of autodividers, like this:

```
$("#MessagesList").listview({
    autodividers: true,
    autodividersSelector: function (li) {
        var out = li.attr('date');
        return out;
    }
}).listview('refresh');
```

And you would get something like this: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/qj3eJ/)**

Now, at this point we have solved your first problem. Now, about your second problem. You can implement listview infinite-scroll with a help of a jQuery plugin called **[Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/)**. It can be used to detect listview has reached bottom, it will then trigger an event which can be used to pull another set of dynamic data and enhancement process will start again.

Or you can take a look at my older example and see how it can be done manually (I prefer this solution over waypoints, it has a better detection): **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Bn2Du/)**

Comment: Thank you for these pointers, I'm going to experiment. As for the dividers, I think they are static. On the exemple shown, the dividers stay on top. For example, monday will stay on top until we reach tuesday. Then monday will disappear, and tuesday will be on top until we reach another day.

Comment: Hey thanks, just implementing it. Now, I've seen your other post about iscrollview. Why not use iscrollviews' iscroll-pullup and pulldown ? I've tried using them but I just cannot make it to display anything or do anything when pulling up/down for now with dynamic content.

Comment: I didn't mentioned them because people I helped usually had more problems with iscrollview then it helped them. That doesn't mean iscrollview is bad, it just take time to get used to. All that to side, you are correct, I will write one tutorial with iscrollview. I use it very often but for other purpose.